# System data types - how to use them in a custom table?

Tags: types, system, axapta

Dynamics AX 2012 has a number of System Data Types (UserId, TableName, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy etc.) These can be found under System documentation, Types in the AOT.

I was wondering how to use these data types in my custom tables. For example, I want to create a custom table and I want TableName and UserId as columns in that table. How do I go about adding those columns to my custom table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [how to turn on CreatedBy, CreatedDateTime, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDateTime](http://dynamicscare.com/blog/how-to-turn-on-the-modified-by-and-created-by-fields-on-a-table/).

Other fields can be created by dragging the extended data type to the `Fields` node of your table or by [creating the field and selecting the extended data type](http://www.slideshare.net/murrayfife/adding-new-fields-to-dynamics-ax-2012-forms). The last method also works with system data types like `UserId`.

Comment: If you already have an EDT of the type you want, yes, you can drag it to a table. In my case I didn't have an EDT that derived from UserId. So, I tried the second method -- created a field of the proper type in my custom table and changed the ExtendedDataType to UserId -- that worked.  If you want to create an EDT that derives from UserId before you do anything else (so that you can reuse it in multiple places), you run into an issue. I found that duplicating one such as TableNameShort and then changing it to whatever you want to works.